# NodeJS & Docker: How to change the default Context an App is under: e.g. /myapp/stuff rather than /stuff

Tags: node.js, express, docker

I have a NodeJS Express application which currently serves an application at the root of the server when node runs.

e.g. The main launch page of the app is currently at:

```
/
```

And script resources are served based on the root:

```
/scripts/mystuff.js
```

We're deploying this using a simple Docker Script utilizing:

```
docker build -t "myapp-0.1.1" .`
```

The Build script contains:

```
FROM node:latest

# Add app directory.
ADD . /app


#RUN chmod 755 /app
#RUN chmod -R a+r /app

WORKDIR /app

# Start the service
#CMD ["chmod a+rx /" && "node", "server"]
#CMD ["node", "server" && chmod a+rx /]
CMD node server && chmod a+rx /
EXPOSE 8080
```

This causes the application to be available at the root of 8080.

We want everything to be under "MyApp":
e.g.
Landing Page at:
/myapp/

All references to all resources under "/myapp"
/myapp/scripts/mystuff.js

Where is the best way to do this? Do we need to change something in Node, or can we change the way the Docker build script is put together?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a specific user in your Dockerfile, as by default, your are root in a container, an example from a Dockerfile

`RUN useradd -d /home/gg -m -s /bin/bash gg
RUN echo gg:gg | chpasswd
RUN echo 'gg ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/gg
RUN chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/gg
USER gg
ENV HOME /home/gg`

Check the doc for USER

https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#user

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not seeing how this answers my question, but I might just be misunderstanding what you're saying. How does this change it so that someone now navigates to http://MYHOST/myapp/ instead of http://MYHOST/ ?

Comment: If you do all this stuff on a Linux server, would you use only the user root ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your node.js application and change the default route to "/myapp" as you want.

For example in the index.js file below the default route is under "/myapp"

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/myapp/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

module.exports = router;